# How to find value of card._id using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I click on a button which has a class 'return' and I want to get an id of the card. Here is a peace of code.

```js
$('.return').on('click', () => {

  let a = $('.return').siblings();
  console.log(a);

})
```

```html
for (let card of cards) { 
table += `
<tr>
  <th scope="row">${card._id}</th>
  <td>${card._visitor}</td>
  <td>${card._bookName}</td>
  <td>${card._borrowDate}</td>
  <td>${card._returnDate==='not fetched'?'' + '
    <button class="return"></button>':card._returnDate}
  </td>
```

Comment: The button has no siblings.

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/) -> [Traversing](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Comment: `$('.return').siblings()` will give you all the siblings for *all* the buttons - not what you want (as you know, just explaining what it does)

Comment: It's not a (direct) duplicate, but this explains arrow functions and `this`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable.   Also useful (linked from that question)   https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#not-just-shorter-syntax-but-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let a = $(this).parent().prevAll("th").text();
```

`$(this)` <- refers to the button that was clicked.
`.parent()` <- to access the `td`
`.prevAll("th")` <- to find the `th` that comes before you `td`
`.text()` <- to get the text aka `${card._id}`

Problem is that your `button` is not the sibling of your `th`

**Demo**

```js
$('.return').on('click', function() {

  let a = $(this).parent().prevAll("th").text();
  console.log(a);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">${card._id}</th>
    <td>${card._visitor}</td>
    <td>${card._bookName}</td>
    <td>${card._borrowDate}</td>
    <td>${card._returnDate==='not fetched'?'' + '
      <button class="return"></button>':card._returnDate}
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your explanation is good but it is not working in my case.  I can't find this.parent(). I get this jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: j…y.fn.init, context: undefined]

Comment: Because your original code uses `()=>` for the click event, so `this` is not the button.  **Don't use `()=>` for click events** - change to `.click(function() {` (other options available)

Comment: @freedomn-m ` Don't use ()=> for click events ` well...that depends on what you want to do in those click functions. If you want to use the clicked element, yes. Don't use arrow functions. But if you want to use the class or the scope or something else...then it's ok to use arrow functions.

Comment: @MihaiT agreed, but I would say, probably 100% (yes 100%) of recent questions asking why their click event isn't working is because `()=>` - so it's an easy rule.  As with all rules, there are exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add the `id` to the button

```
<button class="return" data-id="${card._id}"..
```

then you can access that id without needing to traverse.

Note you're also using `()=>` in the click event, so you won't be able to use `this` to reference the button.  Change to `function()` to get `this`, giving:

```js
$('.return').on('click', function() {

  let id = $(this).data("id");
  console.log(id);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><button class="return" data-id="1">return</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><button class="return" data-id="2">return</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">752</th>
    <td><button class="return" data-id="752">return</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass jquery and use your script when adding cards to attach an onclick method to your button and retrieve the card id

```js
const cards = [{
    _id: 1,
    _returnDate: "not fetched"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    _returnDate: "not fetched"
  }
]
const table = document.querySelector("table")
for (let card of cards) {
  table.innerHTML += ` <tr>
      <th scope="row">${card._id}</th>
      <td> <button class="return" onclick="buttonClick(${card._id});">Click Me</button></td>
      </tr>`
}

function buttonClick(cardId) {
  console.log("card id:", cardId)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```

Comment: so you suggest using jquery ? what year is this ? :) You can say ' won't work if ... ' on every code solution to any problem

Comment: well if he already uses javascript to add HTML inside an element. Why not add an onclick function while you are at it ?

Comment: So you use `jquery` ( an entire library )  just so you can write `$("#idSelector")` instead of `document.getElementById('idSelector')` ? :)) that's some good ' coding ' advice there.